# Web Analytics and Content Reuse

Tags: tridion, templating

We have created a button template where an editor can associate a web analytic tag with it.  The issue is we would like to reuse this button component on the same page but still be able to differentiate where on the page it is coming from.

Has someone encountered this issue before?  We're looking for some insight into the problem and perhaps some ways to solve this without modifying the template.

FYI, we are using Tridion 2009 SP1.

Thanks!

*Updated with HTML*

```
<a href ="/security.jsp" onClick="trackCustomLink('tttt:p:apply-now','Link','onClick');">
   <img src="/images/GICs/applynow-button.gif"  border="0" alt="Apply Now" /></a>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the HTML you are outputting so we can add more useful answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your button is rendered with a component template, it seems like you need to just use the Ordinal Position of the component on the page - Can you specify what kind of templates you are using (VBScript or Modular with DWT or C#)? Base on that we may be able to give you some code samples.

Graham bird has a good article about OrdinalPosition with VBScript at: http://www.grahambird.co.uk/2011/01/ordinalposition/

The idea behind this is that you add the ComponentPresentation.OrdinalPosition value to your analytics code.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the id of the component as a parameter for the web analytics tool.

Comment: That is a good suggestion @Quirijn, probably a combination of the OrdinalPosition AND ComponentURI would give you the most unique case

Comment: Thanks Chris and Quirijn for your response. We are using modular templating with a DWT TBB. Is the ordinal position of a component presentation available to the DWT natively or would we need to push the ordinal position into the package as a variable by say a C# TBB? (which we would then append to the analytics tag)

Comment: I believe you will have to add it to the Engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextVariables collection in your Page Template before calling your render action on your Component Presentation, and then retrieve it from there. But I tend not to use DWTs, so I could be wrong.